# JasperException - File Not Found even when tag is present

Tags: java, maven, jsp, osgi

Alright StackOverflow, I'm coming to you in a time of need.

I've inherited a project with a custom tag library. The project is in AEM, but the problem is more of an issue with the straight Java side of things and is nothing specific to AEM that I am aware of. AEM is built on OSGI, so that *could* be related, but again it's sort of unlikely to be part of the answer.

Essentially, I'm getting an exception on only one of two servers. It says:

> org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: File "/META-INF/tags/helloWorld.tagx" not found

Now - this `helloWorld.tagx` is sort of garbage left in from a template project, but for some reason it's essential. There's a few issues here.

1. The tag *is* in the right location (`META-INF/tags/helloWorld.tagx`) and I'm using the `jsptld-maven-plugin` to generate the `tld` file which looks correct to me.

The configuration for the plugin (as well as the `maven-bundle-plugin`):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.squeakysand.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsptld-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <shortName>myproject</shortName>
                <processTagFiles>true</processTagFiles>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-Activator>com.rebny.taglib.osgi.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Include-Resource>
                        META-INF/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.tld=${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.tld,
                        {maven-resources}
                    </Include-Resource>
                    <Sling-Bundle-Resources>
                        /META-INF/tags
                    </Sling-Bundle-Resources>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And the segment from the resulting tld file:

```
<tag-file>
    <name>helloWorld</name>
    <path>/META-INF/tags/helloWorld.tagx</path>
</tag-file>
```

So it looks fine to me, and I've done a lot of searching and found people with syntax errors, etc. but I don't believe that to be the case here, especially since it works on one server.

2. The weird part is the tag isn't actually *used* anywhere, but removing it doesn't solve the issue. The jsp throwing this error uses other tags, but not this one. There is literally no references to this tag in the entire project - I'm thinking it might be hiding another issue. The error says that it's on line 6 of the JSP, but neither the source JSP or the compiled JSP have anything interesting on line 6, or in the file at all. Again, even compiled JSPs have no reference to this tag!

I'm happy to provide other information. My knowledge of this is pretty poor, so I'm not exactly sure what information is relevant. Any help or troubleshooting tips is greatly appreciated!

Full stack trace [here](https://gist.github.com/jamiecounsell/e5f31bfc5b2839ee816c217b0757628f)

Comment: How do your two machines differ?  e.g. same version of everything, same software, etc?

Comment: the full stacktrace would be helpful

Comment: Which app server / container you are using? Can you, please, provide list of files that are included in WEB-INF/lib? What about TLD  in web.xml - can you provide web.xml? BTW: I'm assuming that your build is simple maven build, without fancy extracting, repacking.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti full stack trace added. https://gist.github.com/jamiecounsell/e5f31bfc5b2839ee816c217b0757628f

Comment: @mikep exact same. In fact, I have a dev server that is a _clone_ of the affected server that behaves just fine.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski it's just AEM running on CentOS 7. No containerization or anything. Since I'm using the `jsptld-maven-plugin`, it generates the tlds at runtime. It'll be a few hours before I can get the generated tld files.

Comment: What about Java version(s)? Perhaps you checked it, but it is worth to ask. A specially if that is all open jdk / oracle jdk...

Comment: Also is it possible that maven cache on both are different and that is giving different results?

Comment: I think, or that was my assumption, that it is build in one place, and executed on different servers. There must be difference somewhere - like different JDK, or AEM in different versions. I don't know it well, just saw many reports about problem, when upgrading from 6.1 to 6.3, some that was fixed with 6.3.11... Strange problem anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to go through [Adobe Daycare](https://daycare.day.com/public/contact.html). They are pretty good about getting you patches. Especially if your client has an existing relationship with them which they should if they are using AEM.

Answer (score 0):

The issue relates to **Scripted tag files are not found**. [Reference](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-7044).

It's a **bug** that states, If a taglib in a bundle, references a tag implemented as a script `(located in /META-INF/tags)` this script is not found as it is **not** searched within the bundle containing the `tld`. It's rather used as a resource on the classpath.

The bug has been Fixed in **JSP 2.3.2**  version. So make use of this JSP version in your project. Moreover, this bug would have been fixed in **AEM 6.3.1.1 Or higher**,

Here, Is a helpful [thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2322688) related to this issue.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but you'll see that I've already commented on that thread. Unfortunately that version of AEM isn't available until late November and that is too far out.